# Agregando funcionalidades

Tags: javascript, funciones, condiciones, function

Me piden hacer lo siguiente, pero la función **puedeComprar** me marca un error, no se que estoy haciendo mal, si alguien pudiera explicarme de favor.

verificar si una persona puede comprar o no un auto. Esta permite al sistema definir si una persona al consultar por un auto, puede comprarlo. Las personas solo sacan los autos en cuotas y tomando dos factores como condición de compra. Una es el costo total: si el total de un auto excede lo que la persona considera caro, no va a comprar el auto. Otra condición es su capacidad de pago en cuotas: si la capacidad de pago en cuotas supera al costo de la cuota, va a poder pagarlo. Si ambas condiciones se cumplen, se realiza la compra.

Es por esto que María te pide que desarrolles la función puedeComprar que reciba por parámetro un auto y una persona y devuelva true si la misma puede comprar el auto.

Una persona va a ser representada mediante un objeto literal de la siguiente forma:

```javascript
{
    nombre: “Juan”,
    capacidadDePagoEnCuotas: 20000,
    capacidadDePagoTotal: 100000
}
```

Código

```javascript
let autos = require('./autos');

let concesionaria = {
    autos: autos,
    buscarAuto: function (patente) {
        for (let i = 0; i <= autos.length; i++) {
            if (patente == autos[i].patente) {
                return autos[i];
            } else if (patente != autos[i].patente && i == (autos.length - 1)) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    },
    venderAuto: function (patente) {
        let autos = this.buscarAuto(patente);
        if (autos) {
            autos.vendido = true
        }
    },
    autosParaLaVenta: function () {
        let carro = this.autos.filter(function (patente) {
            return patente.vendido == false
        });
        return carro
    },
    autosNuevos: function () {
        let carro = this.autosParaLaVenta().filter(function (patente) {
            return patente.km < 100
        });
        return carro;
    },
    listaDeVentas: function () {
        let ventas = this.autos.filter(function (patente) {
            return patente.vendido == true
        });
        let lista = [];
        ventas.forEach(function (costo) {
            lista.push(costo.precio);
        })
        return lista;
    },
    totalDeVentas: function () {
        const total = this.listaDeVentas().reduce((acu, item) => {
            return acu + item;
        }, 0);
        return total;
    },

    puedeComprar: function (auto, persona) {
        if (auto == 12) {
            return true;
        } else if (persona == 30000) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? No se entiende lo que has publicado. Por favor leer [ask]. Queremos ayudarte, pero debes dejar que te ayudemos. Saludos

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras, ah si, perdón...es que en mi función **puedeComprar** no me sale lo que me están pidiendo, de hecho anterior mente estaba así mi función: 
puedeComprar: function (auto, persona) {
        if (auto == 12) {
            return true;
        } else if (persona == 30000) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

pero me marca error y no tengo muy clara la idea de como tengo que hacerlo

Comment: OK, pero eso has de explicarlo en la pregunta. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] y añadir una explicación de eso que comentas. Saludos

Comment: ok, gracias, ya lo modifico

Answer (score 0):

### Enunciado

> Es por esto que María te pide que desarrolles la función puedeComprar que reciba por parámetro un auto y una persona y devuelva true si la misma puede comprar el auto.

Lo anterior indica cómo tiene que ser la firma de la función `puedeComprar`:

Debe ser de la siguiente forma:

```javascript
function puedeComprar(auto, persona) {} // returns boolean
```

---

### Condiciones

> Las personas solo sacan los autos en cuotas y tomando dos factores como condición de compra. Una es el costo total: si el total de un auto excede lo que la persona considera caro, no va a comprar el auto. Otra condición es su capacidad de pago en cuotas: si la capacidad de pago en cuotas supera al costo de la cuota, va a poder pagarlo. Si ambas condiciones se cumplen, se realiza la compra.

En esta parte se indica la lógica que debe tener la función `puedeComprar`, es decir, las condiciones que se deben cumplir para que la función devuelva `true` o `false`.

La primer condición es:

> si el total de un auto excede lo que la persona considera caro, no va a comprar el auto

Recordando cómo es el objeto que representa a una persona:

```javascript
{
    nombre: “Juan”,
    capacidadDePagoEnCuotas: 20000,
    capacidadDePagoTotal: 100000
}
```

Deberíamos comparar el precio del auto con el valor `capacidadDePagoTotal` para ver `el total de un auto excede lo que la persona considera caro`

Esto sería:

```javascript
function puedeComprar(auto, persona) {
   if (auto.total > persona.capacidadDePagoTotal) { // suponiendo que el objeto auto tiene una propiedad "total" (No lo has aclarado en la pregunta)
     return false;
   }
}
```

Lo anterior satisface la primer condición. Pero todavía no es suficiente para cumplir con todo el enunciado.

La segunda condición es:

> si la capacidad de pago en cuotas supera al costo de la cuota, va a poder pagarlo

Ahora deberíamos comparar el precio de 1 cuota del auto, con el valor de `capacidadDePagoEnCuotas` de la persona.

Esto sería:

```javascript
function puedeComprar(auto, persona) {
   let precioPorCuota = auto.total / 12 // suponiendo que sean 12 cuotas (No lo has aclarado en la pregunta)
   if (precioPorCuota > persona.capacidadDePagoEnCuotas) {
     return false;
   }
}
```

---

### Solución

Por último, uniendo ambas condiciones el código podría quedar así:

```javascript
function puedeComprar(auto, persona) {
   if (auto.total > persona.capacidadDePagoTotal) { // suponiendo que el objeto auto tiene una propiedad "total" (No lo has aclarado en la pregunta)
     return false;
   }
   let precioPorCuota = auto.total / 12 // suponiendo que sean 12 cuotas (No lo has aclarado en la pregunta)
   if (precioPorCuota > persona.capacidadDePagoEnCuotas) {
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

---

### Ejemplo de uso

```js
let persona1 = {name: "Pedro", capacidadDePagoTotal: 4000, capacidadDePagoEnCuotas: 400};
let persona2 = {name: "Ana", capacidadDePagoTotal: 6000, capacidadDePagoEnCuotas: 600};
let autoCaro = {total: 5000};
let autoBarato = {total: 3000};

function puedeComprar(auto, persona) {
   if (auto.total > persona.capacidadDePagoTotal) { // suponiendo que el objeto auto tiene una propiedad "total" (No lo has aclarado en la pregunta)
     return false;
   }
   let precioPorCuota = auto.total / 12 // suponiendo que sean 12 cuotas (No lo has aclarado en la pregunta)
   if (precioPorCuota > persona.capacidadDePagoEnCuotas) {
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}

console.log(persona1.name + " puedeComprar autoCaro => " + puedeComprar(autoCaro, persona1));
console.log(persona1.name + " puedeComprar autoBarato => " + puedeComprar(autoBarato, persona1));

console.log(persona2.name + " puedeComprar autoCaro => " + puedeComprar(autoCaro, persona2));
console.log(persona2.name + " puedeComprar autoBarato => " + puedeComprar(autoBarato, persona2));
```